# how to configure wordpress to run with PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

I have a dev wordpress instance and want to test compatibility of WP and plugins with php 7. I installed php 7 using ppa:ondrej/php. Now I have two PHP installations and Wordpress is still using php 5.
How can I configure Wordpress cleanly to use php 7?

I run 
    `update-alternatives --config php`
as suggested by DopeGhoti and php 7 was and is set up as default php.
However, the when calling the phpinfo.php in my wordpress root, it displays php 5 is being used.

Comment: `update-alternatives --config php`.  Also, make sure that Apache only has the php7 module enabled and not the php5 module (or that it is configured to only send `.php5` files to the older version of PHP).

Comment: @DopeGhoti thank you. I tried that and php 7 is selected, but wordpress still uses php 5. see update in question.

Comment: Did you check your Apache module installation settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `libapache2-mod-php7.0` and if it doesn't enable automatically (it should) at install time, enable it with:

```
a2enmod php7.0
```

If `libapache2-mod-php5` is still installed, either disable it first with `a2dismod php5` or uninstall with `apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5`.